# Почему переменная isContains может быть не инициализирована?

Tags: java, коллекции

Код проверяет коллекцию на наличие элемента, но в блоке if else же в любом случае `isContains` получает значение, почему eclipse ругается на то, что `isContains` может быть не инициализирована?

```
public boolean isContains(ArrayList<String> list, String s) {
    String s1 = "";
    String s2 = s.substring(6);
    boolean isContains;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        s1 = list.get(i).substring(6);

        if (s1 == s2) {
            isContains = true;

        } else {
            isContains = false;
        }

    }
    return isContains;
}
```

это метод в котором я вызываю проверку

```
public ArrayList<String> getProductListWithoutDuplicateGoods() {
    listWithoutDuplicates = new ArrayList<String>();

    String s;
    for (int i = 0; i < sortedProduct.size(); i++) {
        s = sortedProduct.get(i);
        if (isContains(listWithoutDuplicates, s) == false) {
            listWithoutDuplicates.add(s);
        }
    }
    return listWithoutDuplicates;
}
```

Comment: `list.size()` может быть равен нулю.

Comment: предполагал такое, насильно запихивал туда  данные, никакого эффекта

Comment: Вы различаете компиляцию и выполнение? Компилятор не знает, какие данные будут в рантайме.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev дело в том, что если ничего не присвоить переменной в месте где она объявляется, то выполнение крашится, а в логе написано, что переменная не инициализирована

Comment: "крашится" не выполнение, а компиляция. Аккуратнее с терминами.

Comment: Метод проверяет наличие элемента в коллекции?? Может использовать метод contains, который есть у самого листа? а еще лучше использовать для таких вещей сет, а не лист, но это уже другая история...

Comment: @Дмитрий я бы с удовольствием им и воспользовался, но в строка данных выглядит примерно так: 34213-Автомобиль, и нужно исключить лишь совпадения по текстовой части записи

Answer (score 1):

Потому, что isContains у Вас является локальной переменной. Локальная переменная не можеть быть не инициализированна (у них отсутствует значение по умолчанию). И проверка этого значения происходит еще во время компиляции, а не в рантайме.
Почитайте статьи про переменные. Минут 10 разобратся, но в них можно найти гораздо более интересную и нужную инфу нежели я тут расскажу) Для примера можете посмотреть статью с javaRush, как по мне там достаточно доходчиво и простым языком все рассписанно. Вот ссылка на эту статью -  https://javarush.ru/groups/posts/609-prisvaivanie-i-inicializacija-v-java

Answer (score 1):

Я не хочу сейчас спрашивать, каким образом в вашей коллекции оказался такой список.
Возможно его изначально нужно было распарсить и привести к виду, в котором с ним будет удобно, безопасно работать (о ресурсах я вообще молчу).
Что делает этот метод "substring(6)" я полагаю вы знаете. И если ваша цифра окажется не 5-значная, то это тоже на вашей совести.
В любом случае, если вы уже захотели сделать такую проверку руками, то, как по мне, стоит делать примерно так...

```
public boolean isContains(final Collection<String> list, final String s) {        
    return list.stream().anyMatch(c->c.substring(6).equals(s));
}
```